# LINQ OrderBy then SELECT specific index

Tags: c#, linq

I have database table with a lot of data in it. I want to order it by column name `TIMESTAMP`, then select any given index of that generated `List`.

```
int index = 1;
query = dbContext.SimpleAisRecords
                 .OrderBy(ship => ship.TIMESTAMP)
                 // How to get wanted index: --> select/take(index)?;
```

The reason I wanna do this is because my table only has dummy-data, and I want to iterate through it. Therefore I want to call this method with desired index. First iteration `index : 1`, and next iteration `index : 2` and so on.
I have seen a lot of questions on how to `Select` then `OrderBy`, `OrderBy` then `Select` and `OrderBy` then `Take`.

But as I said, I need a way to take a specific index of `OrderBy`, not the first or last item of that `OrderBy`.

Is that possible?

Comment: [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) method can accept a selector with index

Comment: I will try this, thanks!

Comment: [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Boolean__) method has the same overload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a specific item using `ElementAt`. E.g:

```
int index = 1;
query = dbContext.SimpleAisRecords
                    .OrderBy(ship => ship.TIMESTAMP)
                    .ElementAt(index)
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use overload of `Where`(the second parameter is `index`):

```
var model = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7 };
var result = model.OrderBy(s => s).Where((s, i) => i > 5).ToList();
```

**UPDATE:**

We can include desired range of indexes and check them in `Where`:

```
var indexes = new List<int>{ 1, 8, 5 };
var model = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6 };
var result = model.OrderBy(s => s)
    .Where((s, i) => indexes.Contains(i)).ToList();
```

Comment: `Skip(5)` would provide the same result as above.  Depending on the exact requirements, `Skip` would arguably translate into a better query.  It's hard to glean exactly what the OP is looking for from the question.

Comment: @Oliver yeah,  however, it looks like `Where` is more powerful, e.g, we can put desired range in `Where` statement

Comment: @StepUp Yeah exactly, it's hard to tell if that's what the OP was looking for.  Upvoted for the update as it shows a specific use-case for that overload.

Comment: @Oliver thanks for your review, valuable comments and upvoting!

Answer (score 1):

I understand that u want to return only wanted index?
if so, you have a lot of ways to do that. 
use this if you want to iterate on the List

```
 int index = 1;
query = dbContext.SimpleAisRecords
                    .OrderBy(ship => ship.TIMESTAMP).ToList();
           var res = query [index ];
```

or you could do like this if u want to only return that value

```
int index = 1;
    query = dbContext.SimpleAisRecords
                        .OrderBy(ship => ship.TIMESTAMP).Skip(index).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this below code

```
int[] model = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 9, 8, 7 };
var result = model.OrderByDescending(x => x).Select((iVal, i) => new {i, iVal}).Where(x => (x.i == 3)).Select(x => x.iVal).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine((int)result);
```